# Multiple database drivers scenario: passing interface as type

Tags: go, interface

Scenario: I've got a database type implementing a number of CRUD operations.

I would like to:

- abstract away the database layer to support multiple databases
- put a cache layer "in front of it" as read-through cache

So my idea was to:

- create a database interface for both postgres specific code, and the cache
- pass the postgres type to the cache constructor so it can use it to from the database

See below for what I tried, resulting in an error for cacheNew() when assigning :

> cannot use dbdriver (variable of type interface{}) as database value in struct literal: missing method GetUser

What is the best way to solve this?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type database interface {
    GetUser(string)
}

type postgres struct {
    hostname string
}

func (p *postgres) GetUser(u string) {
    fmt.Printf("Postgres: GetUser %s\n", u)
}

type cache struct {
    db database
}

func cacheNew(dbdriver interface{}) cache {
    return cache{
        db: dbdriver,
    }
}

func (c *cache) GetUser(u string) {
    fmt.Printf("Cache: GetUser %s\n", u)

    c.db.GetUser(u)
}

func main() {
    // var db database

    db := postgres{
        hostname: "x",
    }
    db.GetUser("joe")

    dbViaCache := cacheNew(db)
    dbViaCache.GetUser("joe")
}
```

Comment: Since `cache`'s field is of type `database`, why then does the constructor have `interface{}` as the argument type? Why don't you just do `cacheNew(dbdriver database)`? What are you trying to achieve by using the empty interface?

Comment: Two mistakes: 01. use the proper type you should `func cacheNew(dbdriver database) cache {`, 02. use the address of var `db`, `dbViaCache := cacheNew(db)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `database` instead of `interface{}` in `cacheNew` function

```
func cacheNew(dbdriver database) cache {
```

`postgres` does not implement `database` since `GetUser` method has pointer receiver. So, send the address of `postgres` type variable in `cacheNew`

```
dbViaCache := cacheNew(&db)
```

Comment: Ha, I overlook that I had to pass `postgres` by pointer, it kinda make sense :-) Thanks for your quick followup!

Comment: Welcome to SO, in your spare time try to read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve your problem add newPostgres constructor. Below I made a correction of your initial code.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type database interface {
    GetUser(string)
}

type postgres struct {
    hostname string
}

func newPostgres(hostname string) *postgres {
    return &postgres{
        hostname: hostname,
    }
}

func (p *postgres) GetUser(u string) {
    fmt.Printf("Postgres: GetUser %s\n", u)
}

type cache struct {
    db database
}

func cacheNew(db database) cache {
    return cache{
        db: db,
    }
}

func (c *cache) GetUser(u string) {
    fmt.Printf("Cache: GetUser %s\n", u)

    c.db.GetUser(u)
}

func main() {
    db := newPostgres("x")

    db.GetUser("joe")

    dbViaCache := cacheNew(db)
    dbViaCache.GetUser("joe")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether it's quite opinion-based I do not recommend to mix database and cache functionality.

I can recommend the following: first create package `cache`, and then start from interface in `cache.go`:

```
// Cache is an interface which abstracts cache providers details for testability and usability
type Cache interface {
    // Get retrieves the content associated with the given key. decoding it into the given
    // pointer.
    //
    // Returns:
    //   - nil if the value was successfully retrieved and ptrValue set
    //   - ErrCacheMiss if the value was not found in the cache
    //   - an implementation specific error otherwise
    Get(key string, ptrValue interface{}) error

    // set the given key/value in the cache, overwriting any existing value
    // associated with that key
    Set(key string, ptrValue interface{}, expires time.Duration) error

}
```

Then you can create files in this package like `inmem.go`, `redis.go`, everything else implementing this interface. You can then prepare YAML config indicated which cache provider you want to use and instantiate it during your server startup.

```
cache:
  active: "redis"
  redis:
    address: "127.0.0.1:6379"
    password: # 
    poolSize: #
```

For database, everything is trickier. From my experience, it is easier to choose database provider once and use [jmoiron/sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) or even native driver, like pure [pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx#performance) for high-loaded handlers. Because of lack of generics and relatively slow reflect, abstractions on database provider in most cases are not practical except for basic CRUD. For very simple situations you can mimic repository pattern

```
type UserRepository interface {
    Get(ctx context.Context, id uint64) (*User, error)
}

type userRepository struct {
    db *sqlx.DB
}

func (r *userRepository) Get(ctx context.Context, id uint64) (*User, error) {
    const query = `SELECT id, email, login, language_id FROM users WHERE id = $1`
    user := &User{}
    if err := r.db.GetContext(ctx, user, query, id); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return user, nil
}
```

Then in your service you will have something like that

```
    key := "app:users#23"
    user := &User{}
    if err := svc.cache.Get(key, user); err != nil {
        user, err = svc.userRepo.Get(userID)
        if err != nil {
            // handle 
        }
        // otherwise, set cache
        go svc.cache.Set(key, user, time.Minutes * 15)
    }

    // perform other actions with user
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer with examples, really appreciated!